# How to load more images on Lazy Loading

Tags: iphone, ios, lazy-loading

In mu UITable view,I am displaying images from server..For that I am using lazy loading.
I can load the images when the rows are on screen.How to increase the number of images loaded.

like- for the first time 3 table cells are visible,and the images on those cells get loaded with 2seconds delay.How can I load the images on next 3 rows at same time ?

I am using below function to load images

```
- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
  {
    if ([imageArray count] > 0)
    {
    NSArray *visiblePaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
    {
        AppRecord *appRecord = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (!appRecord.appIcon) // avoiding the imagen download if already has an image
        {
            [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you use SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: USe SDWebImage. Its vey fast and easy to use for image in tableview

Comment: I have downloaded that...but not working in my xcode

Answer (score 0):

## Your way to do things

You can do that by downloading images on background and when they do finish, you can post a `NSNotification` to a method to reload `tableView`. But while the images are being downloaded, you have to show a loading view or something to the user to tell him that images are being downloaded.

## Suggestion

I don't recommend that to you, the best way is to download each of them in background independently with `SDWebImage` and also make a faster response of your `tableView`. While the image is being downloaded you show a default image (placeholder), after the image is being downloaded this function sets it where it needs to be:

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier;
        CustomCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        //Here is where you set your image URL and it's placeholder
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        
        return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using this code you can just change below key value  and it is just work perfectly with un limited images.

```
kIDStr     = @"id";  
kNameStr   = @"im:name";  
kImageStr  = @"im:image";  
kArtistStr = @"im:artist";  
kEntryStr  = @"entry";
```